How to make WebM screen recording chunks independently processable (for audio extracting)
I am streaming screen recordings from the browser into 5-second WebM chunks using the MediaRecorder API.
The first chunk (root chunk) is independently processable because it contains the necessary EBML headers and metadata. However, subsequent chunks are not independently processable, as they lack the required metadata, which prevents me from extracting audio independently from them.
Problem:
I am unable to extract audio independently from the individual chunks (by using a tool like FFmpeg) due to missing headers, resulting in errors like EBML header parsing failed. The first chunk works fine on its own, but the subsequent chunks also need to be processed independently for audio extraction.
I am looking for a solution using Javascript or FFmpeg to fix these chunks so that I can extract audio independently from each chunk.

Is there a way to repair these chunks post-recording with FFmpeg to include the missing metadata and headers, making them independently processable for audio extraction?
Can FFmpeg be used to reinitialize the EBML headers in each chunk, or is there a command that can add the metadata from the first chunk to subsequent chunks to allow for independent audio extraction?

Additionally, should I consider any changes in the MediaRecorder API to ensure that the chunks are properly formatted for independent processing? The goal is to make each WebM chunk fully independent, allowing me to extract audio independently from each chunk.

Can you provide the command that gives you "EBML header parsing failed"?

(1) Is the real Question something like this: "MediaRecorder in Chrome gives me an H264 video with Opus audio inside a WebM container. I want to extract the Opus audio in order to convert that into AAC (or MP3) for muxing together as MP4 with H264 video and AAC audio"? (2) You need to provide testable files for a faster Answer. Maybe show a link to the saved first 3 chunks (including root chunk).  Can you record sound from a video page (eg: a Youtube tab)?

Not really, all the specs ask for is that once all the chunks are concatenated they should produce a valid file (which means that the first chunk is indeed already valid). Even if you could somehow determine how the chunking is done currently and fix each chunk today, it's not said that they won't change it tomorrow and break your logic entirely. I think you have 2 or 3 alternatives. First, if you can, build the whole file as it's supposed to be (i.e. concatenate all the prior chunks). 2: Create one MediaRecorder per chunk (you'll get a lot of clips though).

3: process the audio stream directly in front-end/send the raw PCM separately.

had a similar task recently. My approach, in ffmeg after recording to I created a m3u8 file for the chunk and pull out some additional metadata with ffprobe, saved the result as text to a light weight db and then ran a job to stitch the playlist together as a m3u8 playlist.

@ DineshKumar ... Accept & Award the provided Answer so I can re-award it back to you. Otherwise it will be lost to the system. You likely need a new bounty with a new Question providing better testable details (eg: What kind of file gives errors in FFmpeg? So let us see such file bytes, to advice you about fixing EBML headers etc).

The following is just useful suggestions. Different browsers will make different MediaRecorder files.Hopefully someone (including yourself) can use it to prepare a solution.
If still not working then share some test files, from your browser, for a better & specific advice.
Regarding FFmpeg:

Is there a way to repair these chunks post-recording with FFmpeg to include the missing metadata and headers, making them independently processable for audio extraction?


Can FFmpeg be used to reinitialize the EBML headers in each chunk, or is there a command that can add the metadata from the first chunk to subsequent chunks to allow for independent audio extraction?

No. Sorry but FFmpeg does not have user commands to process raw binary (eg: get/set a byte value). 
The software you need for such tasks is called a hex editor. 
(A hex editor allows you to copy/paste/write/delete byte values as needed)
Regarding JavaScript:

Should I consider any changes in the MediaRecorder API setup to ensure that the chunks are properly formatted for independent processing? The goal is to make each WebM chunk fully independent, allowing me to extract audio independently from each chunk.

You did not show your "chunk" handling function for deeper advice, but generally it's a No.
Possible Solution:
You say that you are "streaming screen recordings from the browser into 5-second WebM chunks"...
The solution is to do the following on receiving a chunk via Event:

Extract audio part from the audio/video chunk (it is an Array of byte values)

Append a header for WebM audio in front of the extracted audio data.


Extracting depends on the format. I will expand when you update or reply in the comments. 
Hopefully it will be solved soon for you.
